# Datatable c# aspx server side sorting and searching not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, bootstrap-5, .net-4.8

I have a simple webform with a webmethod LoadData that returns json data managed by front-end with javascript and a datatable. The record number is 1000000 records so I understood that I must use processing and serverSide options to true.
Pagination working correctly but sorting and searching do not working.
This is my first application, what I have to do in my app? I'm looking for any example but I don't find nothing.
Once solved this I would like to create a dynamic page where I can set a query as parameter and the table would be generated with dynamic columns.

This is my code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="dataTable" class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr><th>CODCDL</th><th>DESCDL</th></tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr><th>CODCDL</th><th>DESCDL</th></tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dataTable').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "pageLength": 10,
            "searchable": true,
            "sortable": true,
            "ajax": {
                url: "WebForm1.aspx/LoadData", 
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType : "json",
                data: function (d) {
                    return JSON.stringify(d);
                },
                "dataSrc": function (data) {
                    return data.d.data;
                }
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "CODCDL", "name": "CODCDL", "title": "CODCDL"},
                { "data": "DESCDL", "name": "DESCDL", "title": "DESCDL" },
            ],
        }).on('xhr.dt', function (e, settings, json, xhr) {
            // Modifica la struttura del JSON
            json.recordsTotal = json.d.recordsTotal;
            json.recordsFiltered = json.d.recordsFiltered;
            json.draw = json.d.draw;
            json.data = json.d.data;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You really don't want to display a million records to the user! This will slow everything down a lot. Use paging.

Comment: Hi, obviously I use paging, In our application there are a lot of record in many tables and it's possible that the user needs to analyze them. I use OFFSET and FETCH in my SQL Statement and correctly I see data with correct pagination and my WebMethod manage draw, start and length parameters. I don't understand what I have to do in server side modality to sort  and filter the data

Comment: Are you sorting and filtering the records client side? How do you sort and filter a sub selection of your entire data set? Seems like you would need to apply the sort/filter desired to the records before they are returned from the database and then start paging across them.

Comment: Your query would need to incorporate all filtering and sorting; paging (also in the query) is just the final step performed by the DB before returning your results. It won't make sense to apply any client-side sorting/filtering on top of that.